# Installing Font to GIMP 2.8

Tags: gimp, truetype-fonts

I am trying to download a Google Web Font to Gimp 2.8. I copied and pasted the TTF file to the fonts
library, restarted Gimp, but the font still does not show up. I am working on Windows Vista.

Am I missing something? Thanks for helping.

Comment: Can you see the font in another program ?
(notepad for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the GIMP documentation, GIMP 2.8 does accept TTF files. Instead of adding directly to GIMP's
fonts folder, add it to Windows fonts directory. A search for 'fonts' immediately shows the file. 
Adding the file here will make it usable in all applications, including GIMP.

Comment: This is not a solution, but rather a workaround.

Comment: I installed it in the directory, it's still not working